# Get the value not the unit in try catch block in Kotlin using Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

Android kotlin coroutine retrofit.

I want to get the value from the getPropeties to insert it in database. I Need a help for this? I need the value to be an instance of User not the unit value. My viewModel class is given below.

```
    import android.app.Application
    import android.content.Context
    import android.util.Log
    import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
    import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
    import com.example.android.marsrealestate.database.AppDatabase
    import com.example.android.marsrealestate.database.User
    import com.example.android.marsrealestate.database.UserDao
    import com.example.android.marsrealestate.network.UsersApi
    import com.example.android.marsrealestate.network.UsersProperty
    import kotlinx.coroutines.*
    import retrofit2.Call
    import retrofit2.Callback
    import retrofit2.Response


    class OverviewViewModel(val database: UserDao,
                            application: Application): ViewModel() {
        private var viewModelJob = Job()
        private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(
                viewModelJob + Dispatchers.Main )
        private var user = MutableLiveData<User?>()
        // The internal MutableLiveData String that stores the most recent response
        private val _response = MutableLiveData<String>()

        // The external immutable LiveData for the response String
        val response: LiveData<String>
            get() = _response

        init {
            getUsersProperties()

        }

        private fun getUsersProperties(){
            coroutineScope.launch {
                var getPropertiesDeferred =
                        UsersApi.retrofitService.getProperties()
                try {
                    var listResult = getPropertiesDeferred.await()
                    //database.insertUser(listResult)
                    _response.value =
                            "Success: ${listResult} Mars properties retrieved"

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    _response.value = "Failure: ${e.message}"
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCleared() {
            super.onCleared()
            viewModelJob.cancel()
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `launch`,

> Launch is used to perform asynchronous fire and forget type of
>   operations where you are not interested in the result of operation.

Instead, you can use `async`,

> Async is used to perform asynchronous computation where you expect a
>   result of the computation in the future

```
private fun getUsersProperties() =
            coroutineScope.async {
                var getPropertiesDeferred =
                        UsersApi.retrofitService.getProperties()
                try {
                    var listResult = getPropertiesDeferred.await()
                    //database.insertUser(listResult)
                    _response.value =
                            "Success: ${listResult} Mars properties retrieved"

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    _response.value = "Failure: ${e.message}"
                }
              // =================================================
              // ========= Return whatever result you want =======
              // =================================================
            }
```

can you also show what is the type signature of `getProperties`?

Comment: Thanks! @pritam for getproperties () it's an error i just wanted to write getUsersProperties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was very helpful.